# How do I Maximize a .NET MAUI Win

Tags: c#, maui

How do I start my .NET Maui Windows and Android apps with the screen windows maximized?

I tried using this code, but it cannot find DLLImport.

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WindowHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(IWindow), (handler, view) =>
        {
#if WINDOWS
            var nativeWindow = handler.PlatformView;
            nativeWindow.Activate();
            IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(nativeWindow);
            ShowWindow(windowHandle, 3);
#endif
        });

      
    }
#if WINDOWS
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please include the error message to your post and it's unclear that you need a DllImport code below. Possibly, you haven't uses the namespace `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

```
#if WINDOWS
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);
#endif
```

Alternatively, you can also plug the code below into your `MauiApp.CreateBuilder()` method to implement the full-screen or maximize the screen on Windows platform:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents; 
#if WINDOWS

using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Windows.Graphics;

#endif


#if WINDOWS 

builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
{
       events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
       {
             wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
            {
                    
            IntPtr hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);

            WindowId myWndId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);

            var _appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(myWndId);

            _appWindow.SetPresenter(AppWindowPresenterKind.FullScreen);
            
             window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true; 


             });

      });
});
#endif
```